# Ubuntu 20.04 Windriver Workbench " java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError " error

Tags: java, eclipse, x86-64, ubuntu-20.04, wind-river-workbench

Im working on Linux server and i took a directory with Windriver from another server (with scp).
the same procedure worked on another servers.

When i run it, the GUI appears, and after i choose workspace directory i get an error (saying watch the log)

**my linux:**

```
Linux Itzhak-r-ubuntu 5.15.0-92-generic #102~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 15 13:09:14 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**the log error:**

```
`!SESSION 2024-02-01 14:29:33.257 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130131-0800/WB20140715-0750
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IL
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-02-01 14:29:40.170
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.Env.setEnv(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
        at com.windriver.core.runtime.jni.Env.setEnv(Native Method)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WREnv.setSystemEnv(WREnv.java:805)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.initWorkbenchEnvironment(WRInstallRegistry.java:631)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.init(WRInstallRegistry.java:484)
        at com.windriver.ide.common.core.installregistry.WRInstallRegistry.getInstance(WRInstallRegistry.java:550)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.checkPreconditions(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:148)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.CopyOfIDEApplication.start(CopyOfIDEApplication.java:136)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.access$2(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:1)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.start(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WRWBMain.main(WRWBMain.java:37)
`
```

**my java:**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_392"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_392-8u392-ga-1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.392-b08, mixed mode)
```

thanks for help :)

1. i had issue with missing so's (shared objects) and after a search on the internet i installed some and then the gui could run.

```
no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-3836.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Can't load library: /root/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so
```

2. i tried install the required libraries that mentianed on windriver web:
   `$ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \ build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect \ xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping libsdl1.2-dev xterm`

Comment: The log shows that is 32 bit and is actually running Java 1.6, it seems to be based on Eclipse 3.8.2 which is 12 years and 28 releases old. It is probably going to be difficult to get this to run on a modern system.

Comment: i downloaded advanced version from the windriver website to see what is the reaction to another version, and i got the same error.
also in other servers it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I needed to install `libpango1.0-dev:i386` and then `libpangox-1.0-dev:i386`.